# (Ruby ON Rails) Write spec for Facebook ID and validate a FB page or group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, rspec

I a newbie trying to write a [Ruby ON Rails]  spec to make sure user insert is Facebook ID and I can't find anywhere for validate user FB id and direct link to it once clicked. Found https://graph.facebook.com/ but still unsure how to use it.

```
  {
    "id": "40796308305",
    "name": "Coca-Cola",
    "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/hs236.ash2/50516_40796308305_7651_s.jpg",
    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola",
    "category": "Consumer_products",
    "website": "http://www.coca-cola.com",
    "username": "coca-cola",
    "products": "Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in history, as well as the best-known product in the world.\n\nCreated in Atlanta, Georgia, by Dr. John S. Pemberton, Coca-Cola was first offered as a fountain beverage by mixing Coca-Cola syrup with carbonated water. Coca-Cola was introduced in 1886, patented in 1887, registered as a trademark in 1893 and by 1895 it was being sold in every state and territory in the United States. In 1899, The Coca-Cola Company began franchised bottling operations in the United States.\n\nCoca-Cola might owe its origins to the United States, but its popularity has made it truly universal. Today, you can find Coca-Cola in virtually every part of the world.",
    "fan_count": 17367199
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use introspection in Graph API by adding `metadata` field while requesting object information from Graph API to discover the type of object:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/40796308305?metadata=1
```

This will return additional object metadata including `type` property which will be according to Object Type one of: `user`, `page`, `group`, `status`, `photo`, etc...